# Windows Forms, can't change IME mode?

Tags: windows, winforms, ime

I simply created a Windows Forms application in Visual Studio using the template and launched it. I want to receive text input without using a standard text box. When the form is active, I'm able to change the input language. But I cannot change IME mode. E.g. when the input language is Japanese, the IME mode icon in the tray becomes a circle with a cross in it. When I hover the mouse over, the tooltip says "IME disabled". Any ideas? Thanks in advance.